# Erlang error on send to registered process

Tags: concurrency, process, erlang, message, primes

I'm trying to make Erlang program that finds prime numbers with processes (ineffective, I know, but hey, it's just for fun :) ) - something along the lines of [numbersimulation.com](http://numbersimulation.com).

On each "tick" the server spawns new process ("number") that increments its counter. If counter == that number, it's a factor, so we let server know. If server doesn't get any messages, it's a prime number.

On small numbers (primes upto N, the `server(50,L)` line) it's okay, but on the bigger ones it crashes with:

`Error in process <0.46.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{primes,number,2,[{file,"primes.erl"},{line,31}]}]}`

The line 31 is the `server ! hit` one - but **I don't understand why it fails.** Maybe the line that fails is the one after, `number(N,1)` ? **But why would that fail?**

The code:

```
-module(primes).
-compile(export_all).

main() ->
  pg:create(numbers),
  Server_PID = spawn(?MODULE,server,[]),
  register(server,Server_PID),
  ok.

server()     -> server(2,[]).
server(50,L) -> io:format("Primes: ~p~n",[L]);
server(N,L)  ->
  Num_PID = spawn(?MODULE,number,[N]),
  pg:join(numbers,Num_PID),
  pg:send(numbers,tick),
  receive
    hit ->
      flush(),
      server(N+1,L)
  after 100 ->
      server(N+1,[N|L])
  end.

number(N)   -> receive {pg_message,_,_,tick} -> number(N,1) end.
number(N,I) ->
  receive
    {pg_message,_,_,tick} ->
      if
        N =:= I ->
          server ! hit,
          number(N,1);
        true ->
          number(N,I+1)
      end
  end.

flush() ->
  receive _ -> flush()
  after   0 -> ok end.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a registered process dies the name it was registered under is no longer registered. While sending a message to a pid which refers to a dead process is perfectly legal (the message just disappears) sending to an unregistered name is an error, even if the name was once registered.

In your code the `server` process does 50 loops spawning a new process and waiting for a `hit` message or timeout. After that the `server/2` function ends and the `server` process dies. When it dies the name `server` is no longer registered so trying to send a message to it generates a `badarg` error.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it. The other processes really were sending messages to unregistered name.