# Erlang message to non-existent PID

Tags: erlang

What does the Erlang runtime do with a message sent to a non-existent process? For example, a process is spawned, and then later after it terminates another process sends a message to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is dropped. Per [the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/communication.html#id67927):

> If the receiver has terminated, the signal will not arrive...

Also see [this answer from rvirding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698616/8446), who probably knows what he's talking about:

> While sending a message to a pid which refers to a dead process is perfectly legal (the message just disappears)...

Answer (score 4):

If the message is sent to a PID, then the message will disappear into the void. You can even send to non-existing PIDs...

```
1> list_to_pid("<0.0.1>").
<0.0.1>
2> v(1) ! foo.
foo
```

If the message is sent to an atom, the atom has to be the registered name of a PID at the moment of the sending, or the send will crash...

```
3> spawn(fun() -> register(name, self()), then_exit end).
<0.36.0>
4> name ! foo.
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  !/2
        called as name ! foo
```