# What happens when I send a message to a defunct process in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Does the message go into "/dev/null"? That's what I hope would happen.

Seems that the ! operator does not tell the sender that the recipient was dead to begin with if the first operand is a pid, as opposed to an atom. I guess this would not be useful, since the recipient could just die immediately after receiving the message, and the sender wouldn't find out about that either.

But I feel like the sender should get some kind of error, since that's what happens when the first operand is an atom instead of a pid. E.g.

```
> register(am_i_defunct, P=spawn_link(fun() -> timer:sleep(3000) end)).
true
> am_i_defunct ! herp.                                                       
herp
> am_i_defunct ! herp.
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  !/2
        called as am_i_defunct ! herp
> P ! derp.
derp
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erlang message to non-existent PID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430114/erlang-message-to-non-existent-pid)

Answer (score 5):

Erlang ! operator is equivalent of `erlang:send/2`

There is a bit difference between sending to known pid and sending to registered process (local, remote). Later case could be considered as a combination of `whereis(name)` and send. whereis is a part that is failing when you try to send to failed process using atom.

If pid is known, it does not matter if the process exists. ! will just return a message immediately and schedule it for async delivery. If process is dead it will go to `/dev/null`. Conceptually to provide transparent experience for both remote and local processes there is not process existence check made as checking for process existence on remote will cause a ping time delay.

One could use `monitor` and `link` functions to get notifications on target process failures.

If you are interested in synchronous 'call' to process, it is better to consider using `gen_server` behavior providing all necessary wrapping async around message passing.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like for consistency, the whereis error ought not propagate beyond ! or send. Oh well.